# how to display BLOB content in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

how can i display the content on a BLOB? I tried this code

```
openBlob = fileBuffer => {
var BLob = require('blob');
const file = new BLob([fileBuffer, blob]); // You could also add the MIME type here as { 
type: "application/pdf" }
const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
console.log("fileURL" + fileURL)
window.open(fileURL, "_blank_");
 };

render() {
const archivioItems = this.state.archivio.map((archivio, i) => {
  return (
    <tr key={archivio.hash_referto}>
      <td>{archivio.tipo_esame}</td>
      <td>{archivio.data_esame}</td>
      <td>
        <Tab icon={<AssignmentIcon />}              
          className="tab"
           onClick={() => this.openBlob(archivio.uri)}></Tab>
      </td>
    </tr>
  )
})
```

but it says that "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'blob'" and when i click on the Assignment Icon it says that BLob is not defined.
How can i fix it?

Comment: From your given code 'blob' is not declared anywhere.
`new BLob([fileBuffer, blob]);` is the first time you have used the variable blob.
Where do you initiate lowercased blob?

Comment: The require is not getting the blob module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the 'blob' packet reference and your require call does not resolve it. Install the packet with `npm install blob`.

You also have a typo on the new 'BLob', so make it so

```
const file = new Blob([fileBuffer, blob]);
```

EDIT: Do also add the MIME type that you have left out in comments for the new Blob call!

```
{ type: "application/pdf" }
```

Comment: yeah thank you, it worked! but how come it display only [object Object]? How can i see or download the file i'm trying to open?